# Could not load type 'Hangfire.HangfireEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions' from assembly 'Hangfire.AspNetCore when running as a docker container

Tags: c#, docker, containers, hangfire

I am unable to run a docker container with a .NET 5 application that uses Hangfire.
Locally it's all good.
But then I build the image with Azure pipelines, save in Azure Container Registry and try to run it locally. The exception I get is:

```
Starting app for environment Production
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Hangfire.HangfireEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions' from assembly 'Hangfire.AspNetCore, Version=1.7.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
         at MyCompany.Platform.Scheduler.WebApi.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_1(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
         at MyCompany.Platform.Scheduler.WebApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/WebApi/Startup.cs:line 56
         at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Hangfire.HangfireEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions' from assembly 'Hangfire.AspNetCore, Version=1.7.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at MyCompany.Platform.Scheduler.WebApi.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_1(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at MyCompany.Platform.Scheduler.WebApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/WebApi/Startup.cs:line 56
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at MyCompany.Platform.Scheduler.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/WebApi/Program.cs:line 10
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

This is my azure pipelines

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

variables:
  imageName: 'my-scheduler'

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: 'Build'
    jobs:
      - job: 'Build'
        displayName: 'Restore and compile'
        steps:
          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 5.0.x'
            inputs:
              version: '5.0.x'
              includePreviewVersions: true
          - script: dotnet restore --no-cache --force
            displayName: 'Restore dependencies'
          - script: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
            displayName: 'Build with Release Configuration'
          - script: dotnet vstest test/*FunctionalTests/bin/Release/**/*FunctionalTests.dll
            displayName: 'Run functional tests'
          - script: dotnet publish -c Release -o out
            displayName: 'Publish to folder'
          - task: Docker@2
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'saswcr-service-connection'
              command: 'login'
          - task: Docker@2
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'saswcr-service-connection'
              repository: $(imageName)
              command: 'buildAndPush'
              dockerfile: './Dockerfile'
              tags: |
                latest
                $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

And this is how I run the container locally after logging into my ACR

```
docker run --name my-scheduler -p 8080:80 saswcr.azurecr.io/my-scheduler:20201124.4
```

I'm running out of ideas. The versions of hangfire I use:

```
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.18" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.18" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.MemoryStorage" Version="1.7.0" />
```

Maybe there is something wrong with the image creation, but I cannot think what exactly.

If I do the following to see the contents of my container `docker export $(docker ps -lq) | tar tf -`
I see:

```
$ docker export $(docker ps -lq) | tar tf -
.dockerenv
Application.deps.json
Application.dll
Application.pdb
Azure.Core.dll
Azure.Identity.dll
Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.dll
Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll
Castle.Core.dll
CodeCoverage/
CodeCoverage/CodeCoverage.config
CodeCoverage/CodeCoverage.exe
CodeCoverage/amd64/
CodeCoverage/amd64/covrun64.dll
CodeCoverage/amd64/msdia140.dll
CodeCoverage/codecoveragemessages.dll
CodeCoverage/covrun32.dll
CodeCoverage/msdia140.dll
FluentAssertions.dll
Hangfire.AspNetCore.dll
Hangfire.Core.dll
Hangfire.MemoryStorage.dll
Hangfire.SqlServer.dll
Infra.Hangfire.deps.json
Infra.Hangfire.dll
Infra.Hangfire.pdb
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
Microsoft.CodeCoverage.props
Microsoft.CodeCoverage.targets
Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.Views.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Web.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll
Microsoft.OpenApi.dll
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll
Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll
Microsoft.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeCoverage.Shim.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceDataCollector.dll
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
Mono.Cecil.Mdb.dll
Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll
Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll
Mono.Cecil.dll
Moq.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
NuGet.Frameworks.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
System.Buffers.dll
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
System.Data.SqlClient.dll
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
System.Security.AccessControl.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll
System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
System.Threading.dll
UseCases/
UseCases/AddJob/
UseCases/AddJob/simple_job.json
UseCases/AddJob/simple_job_with_url_parameters.json
WebApi
WebApi.FunctionalTests.deps.json
WebApi.FunctionalTests.dll
WebApi.FunctionalTests.pdb
WebApi.FunctionalTests.runtimeconfig.json
WebApi.deps.json
WebApi.dll
WebApi.pdb
WebApi.runtimeconfig.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Local.json
appsettings.Production.json
appsettings.Qa.json
appsettings.Test.json
appsettings.json
bin/
etc.
```

The line that seems to be causing the issue is:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints
      .MapHangfireDashboard(HangfireConstants.DashboardUrl)
      .RequireAuthorization(PolicyConstants.DashboardPolicy);
});
```

What could be the reason? And why does it happen in docker container and not outside?

**UPDATE 1 2020-11-24:**
Interesting finding. I've generated a docker image for the same code, only this time using GitLab CI, Gitlab container repository and kaniko (I'm more familiar with this approach than Azure DevOps) as follows:

```
default:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

variables:
  PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR: publish
  ENTRYPOINT_DLL: WebApi.dll
  WEB_APP_HOOK: $WEB_APP_HOOK

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - publish
  - delivery
  - release

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build -c Release --no-restore
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test
    expire_in: 1 hour

unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script: dotnet vstest test/*UnitTests/bin/Release/**/*UnitTests.dll --Blame
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/*UnitTests/*UnitTests.csproj

functional_tests:
  stage: test
  script: dotnet vstest test/*FunctionalTests/bin/Release/**/*FunctionalTests.dll --Blame
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/*FunctionalTests/*FunctionalTests.csproj

publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - dotnet publish -c Release -o $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - publish/
    expire_in: 1 hour

build_image:
  stage: delivery
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - echo "Generating $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    - echo "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "COPY $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR ." >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "EXPOSE 80" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "ENTRYPOINT [\"dotnet\", \"$ENTRYPOINT_DLL\"]" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    # @see https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/1227
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo "Displaying files.."
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - cat /kaniko/.docker/config.json
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

Then I run the container as:

```
docker run --name cubic-scheduler -p 8080:80 registry.gitlab.com/cubictelecom/my-scheduler
```

This time, with this way of creating the docker image, it works fine. So it seems the problem is indeed with how the docker image is created. **But what's the problem exactly and why it has such an effect on hangfire?**

**UPDATE 2 2020-11-24:**
Dependencies are as follows:

**WebApi**

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Infra.Hangfire\Infra.Hangfire.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Application

```
no dependencies.
```

Infra.Hangfire

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.18" />
  <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.18" />
  <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.MemoryStorage" Version="1.7.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.7.18" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

As you can see, there is no conflict in versions as it uses a clean architecture approach where all the third party dependencies are in infra layer (and web api). In any case, it works fine locally, and it works fine as a docker container when creating it with kaniko and gitlab. The problem must be in how I create it for Azure DevOps.

Comment: try to align version of the package Hangfire.AspNetCore in all project refrenced in your solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is aligned, in fact I´m using a clean architecture approach and only one package has dependency to hangfire. I´ll update it on the question

Comment: in this case , to confirm that the problem is belong to build/deploying process , i would suggest to download the content deployed in the container to your local and try to run dll files directly with dotnet run commands. (maybe problem with some file access permission in the container , so this would be the best solution to check that)